# To programmatically disable IE-8 compatibility mode for the site running in intranet and rendering .xhtml pages

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf-2, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a JSF application with .xhtml pages running in intranet.I tried removing default meta tag and add the meta tag

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

But there is no use.Is this solution only for plain html pages or is there any other way using which i can programmatically disable compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the compatibility mode for all your JSF pages you **better** use a filter for this:

**Java**

```
public class NoCompatibilityMode implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI().endsWith(".js.jsf")
                || ((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI().endsWith(".css.jsf")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"); // No more Compatibility Mode
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NoCompatibilityMode</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.name.NoCompatibilityMode</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NoCompatibilityMode</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```