# Disable internet explorer compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2

By default, `internet explorer 11` (on windows 10) have `compatibility mode` enabled for `intranet`.

Is there a solution to automatically disable that option with a jsf2 page ?

I already tried

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in the header.

Also tried

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</f:facet>
```

But it is not working.  Internet explorer remains in compatibility mode.

```
HTML1202: http://...:7001/....jsf is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.
```

And it's quite annoying to ask many hundred of users to go in the options and disable it manually.

Comment: Change your development environment to English. You'll find so MANY MORE matches in Google when copypasting an English error message there.

Comment: Ok, I put it in english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315643/to-programmatically-disable-ie-8-compatibility-mode-for-the-site-running-in-intr ?

Comment: I tried but it is not working.  I see the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` in the response header but still got the `HTML1202` message.